# A question about Hyperabelian Groups

Tags: group-theory

A group $G$ is a hyperabelian group if has a ascending normal series with abelian factors.
Prove that $F(G)$ is a hyperabelian group for all group $G$, where $F(G)$ is the Fitting subgroup of the group $G$.

Comment: Remark: If $G$ is a group,then $F(G)$ is the subgroup generated by all normal nilpotents subgroups of $G$, ie, $F(G) = \displaystyle\prod_{N \unlhd G} N,$ and $N$ is nilpotent

Comment: If $G$ is finite, we can think of $ F (G) $ as a finite product of $ N $, then we can create an ascending chain of subgroups to meet the definition. Is true? It seems to me also that if $\mid G \mid$ is finite, this idea can be applied. But what to do otherwise, ie, if what should I do if the cardinality of $G$ is not countable?

Comment: For a nilpotent group, the lower central series consists of characteristic subgroups, and has abelian factor groups. So can't you just introduce some well-ordering on the set of all normal nilpotent subgroups of $G$, and then attach all of their lower central series together according to to that ordering, to get the required ascending normal series for $F(G)$?

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand your comment. My ideas for finite groups (or enumerable cardinality) are not correct ?. My English is very bad. You can explain that again, please?

Comment: @AgenorAndrade: Derek suggested a way to find the normal series. I agree his suggestion works. His suggestion is very similar to yours. His suggestion works with infinite groups.

Answer (score 1):

I will try and write this out in a bit more detail. Label the normal nilpotent subgroups $N$ of $G$ as $N_i$, where $i$ ranges over some well-ordered set $I$. Let

$1=N_{i0} < N_{i1} < \cdots N_{ik_i} = N_i$

be the upper central series (the lower central series would work just as well, but the notation works better going upwards) of $N_i$.

Now, for $i \in I$, define $M_i$ to be the (normal) subroup of $G$ generated by all $N_j$ with $j < i$ and, for $0 \le j \le k_i$, let $L_{ij} = M_iN_{ij}$.

Now the indexing set of the $L_{ij}$ subgroups is $\{ (i,j) \mid i \in I, 0 \le j \le k_i\}$, which is well-order by $(i,j) < (i',j')$ if either $i<i'$ or $i=i'$ and $j<j'$. Furthermore, the $N_{ij}$ are all normal in $G$ (because $N_{ij}$ is characteristic in $N_i$), and $M_{i,j+1}/M_{ij}$ is isomorphic to a quotient group of the abelian group $N_{i,j+1}/N_{ij}$, and hence is abelian.

Since $F(G)$ is generated by the $N_i$, the union of the $L_{ij}$ is $F(G)$. So $L_{ij}$ is an ascending normal series for $F(G)$ with abelian factors, and hence $F(G)$ is hyperabelian.