# Proof about Hyperabelian Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm currently studying for my exams and came across nd old exam exercise which i can't solve.

I want to prove that: Every Qoutientgroup of a Hyperabelian Group is again Hyperabelian.
We defined Hyperabelian as: Every non trivial Qoutientgroup group of G has a nontrivial abelian normal subgroup, Than G is said to be hyperabelian
It's obvious that this statement is true by it's definiton but i'm struggeling with the formal proof

I'm sure that the answer is constructed through the third Isomorphism theorem. By the isomorphism theorem every Normal subgroup of a Qoutient group G/K is of the form N/K so again a qoutient but to construct the next step we would need to take a Qoutient of a Qoutient group and i'm not sure if im allowed to do this without further information.
Could someone provide a sketch for the proof or explain me which steps i have to take.

Comment: mistake on my part, wanted to say G is hyperabelian if it's statsfiyng the given condition. And yes I saw this post but his defintion is way stronger than mine

Comment: The definition [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419647/a-question-about-hyperabelian-groups) is: A group $G$ is a hyperabelian group if has a ascending normal series with abelian factors. The definition [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Hyperabelian_group) says: A hyperabelian group is a group which possesses an ascending (possibly transfinite) normal series where all the successive quotients are Abelian. So this seems to be the right definition.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that any quotient of $G/K$ has a nontrivial normal abelian subgroup.

Use the isomorphism theorem: $(G/K)/(N/K)\cong G/N$. The right hand side of the isomorphism has a nontrivial normal abelian subgroup, hence the left hand side does as well.